# Site's admin created with wpmu_create_blog accessible only on 2nd attempt

Tags: multisite, wp-admin, admin, wp-redirect

I let users create sites not via the standard registration method rather via a custom plugin. I use `wpmu_create_blog`, then add the user to the new blog as a user with a custom role and then and then `wp_redirect` the user to the new site's admin:

```
$new_blog_id = wpmu_create_blog( $newdomain, $path, $title, $user_id, $meta, get_current_network_id() );
add_user_to_blog($new_blog_id, get_current_user_id(), 'my_custom_role');
$blog = get_blog_details($new_blog_id,true);
$blog_url = $blog->siteurl;
$redirect_url = $blog_url . '/wp-admin';

wp_redirect( add_query_arg(array(
    'custom_notice' => 'a_custom_notice'
),$redirect_url));
```

What happens is, the user lands on the new site admin with a message: Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page:

[image]

Then when they hit refresh all is suddenly good...

How do I make the new site's admin accesible to the new user on the 1st attempt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TLDR

`user_roles` option is broken, it can be fixed by updating the db, see the solution below.

### Who & Why

I was able to recreate your issue and analyze it. As you can see in the error it is clearly a matter of permissions and capabilities, and it turns out that the whole thing is because wp_xx_user_roles option.

When avoiding the regular registration process, as you are trying to do, the globals `$wpdb` and `$wp_roles` are already exist, and when you use `wpmu_create_blog` from within your site, the very-important option `wp_xx_user_roles` (the xx is for the blog id) is written with the current viewed blog id, and not the new one just created.

My guess is that when creating a new blog from the registration page, wordpress is not considering any blog to be the current blog, so when it uses a brand new wp_roles class instance, instead of using the already-set globals `$wpdb` and `$wp_roles`;

I couldn't find any civil way to address this issue, so we'll do it ugly.
The ugly solution is to update the blog id in `user_roles` option name after creating a new blog, like so:

```
    function replace_wrong_user_roles_option( $new_blog_id ){
        global $wpdb, $wp_roles;

        $current_blog_id = get_current_blog_id();
        if( $current_blog_id == $new_blog_id )
            return true;

        $prefix_length        = strlen( $wpdb->prefix );
        $blog_prefix_length   = strlen( $new_blog_id.'_' );
        $blog_prefix_position = strrpos ( $current_prefix, $new_blog_id.'_' );

        // only on new wpmu, when main blog prefix is without the blog_id
        if($current_blog_id == 1 && !$blog_prefix_position){
            $new_blog_prefix = $wpdb->prefix.$new_blog_id.'_';
        }else{
            $new_blog_prefix = str_replace(get_current_blog_id(), $new_blog_id, $wpdb->prefix);
        }

        return $wpdb->update(
            $new_blog_prefix.'options',
            array( 'option_name' => $new_blog_prefix.'user_roles' ),
            array( 'option_name' => $wpdb->prefix.'user_roles' )
        );
    }
```

And you can insert that function call right after you create your blog:

```
    $new_blog_id = wpmu_create_blog( $newdomain, $path, $title, $user_id, $meta, get_current_network_id() );
    replace_wrong_user_roles_option( $new_blog_id );
    add_user_to_blog($new_blog_id, get_current_user_id(), 'my_custom_role');
    $blog = get_blog_details($new_blog_id,true);
    $blog_url = $blog->siteurl;
    $redirect_url = $blog_url . '/wp-admin';

    wp_redirect( add_query_arg(array(
        'custom_notice' => 'a_custom_notice'
    ),$redirect_url));
```

Comment: all in all you are right. I didn't use your solution but it did point me to find the true bug: I created the role only after adding the user to the blog, so I switched the order and things work now. That said, my problem is solved and I mark your answer as correct.

Comment: @shaharsol I guess it is fair to mark this answer as correct to award the bounty. But for other users having a similar problem, you should post the correct solution for this problem as a new accepted answer afterwards. Having it in a comment can be overseen to easily.